# How to fix corrupted Windows partition from Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

In my laptop I have single 500 GB hard disk and I had Windows 7 OS on it till now. I wanted to install Ubuntu along side with it so I did following:

1. Using windows partitioning tool created two partitions (drives). One
   400 GB drive for windows and other 65 GB drive for Ubuntu
2. Installed Ubuntu 16 using bootable USB

During installation Ubuntu asked me to give size of OS so I gave 25 GB for OS and 35 GB extra for other things. Now Ubuntu is installed but I am facing following problems:

1. Ubuntu is complaining about low disk space - It has used up almost 25 GB and not able to use remaining 35 GB empty partition.
2. I am seeing following multiple partitions in Ubuntu which I never created. Why there are so many partitions?

[image: Output of df -h command]

3. I wanted to have dual boot system but I am not able to start Windows - Whenever I try to start windows it loads file and starts checking for file system problems but that process doesn't finish even if I wait for couple of hours and I can never login to Windows. How can I fix this Windows problem? I can reinstall Windows 7 if required but I do not want to loose any existing data on that 400 GB partition.

Here is the screenshot from Gparted.
[image: screen shot from Gparted]

Comment: are Win7 and ubuntu nstalled in the same mode?  EFI vs Legacy?

Comment: I am not sure in which mode I installed Ubuntu. I had Windows 7 since last 7 years, I never really touched it or reinstalled it.

Comment: can you post your partition information from gparted?